# KnockoutJS options binding: display only non-empty items

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have array: `items = [,,,,5,,7,,,10,....,1000,.....10000]`

And i want display select like next

```
<select>
     <option value="5">word 1</option>
     <option value="7">word 1</option>
     <option value="10">word 1</option>
     <option value="1000">word 1</option>
     <option value="10000">word 1</option>
</select>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a ko.computed to filter out the null entries.  See code below.

```
vm = {};
vm.items = ko.observableArray( [, , , , 5, , 7, , , 10, 1000, 10000]);

//filter the items using the filter text
vm.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item != null;
        });
}, vm);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I created a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/qd6P5/4/